# Why is the composition of China's foreign exchange reserves classified information?

Tags: economy, china, currency

> The exact composition of China's foreign exchange reserves is
> classified information.[7][8] In July 2019, China's State
> Administration of Foreign Exchange announced that at the end of 2014,
> US dollar assets accounted for 58% of China's total reserves, down
> from 79% in 2005; adding that its share of US currency assets was
> lower than the global average of 65% in 2014.[9] Analysts believe the
> remaining foreign exchange assets are held mostly in Euros, Japanese
> Yen, and British pounds.[8]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign-exchange_reserves_of_China

Why is the composition of China's foreign exchange reserves classified information? Is there an advantage of keeping it secret? It says it's a secret then the next sentence said they said what the composition was in 2014, so did they make it a classified information recently?

Comment: I'll bet the 2014 composition was classified in 2014. 10-year-old data is not very useful now, so it's safe to declassify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in my answer to your other question [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80144/what-advantages-does-china-benefit-from-hiding-a-large-amount-of-currency-reserv/80150#80150), it is normal for governments to not reveal the detailed composition of their foreign exchange reserves. This is believed to make them more resistant to speculative attack, or other forms of market manipulation, by currency traders.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
>
> Why is the composition of China's foreign exchange reserves classified information?

Kind of what Charlie Evans said in his answer only with a Chinese twist.

China is a country which tightly controls the value of their currency.  They peg it to the dollar rather than letting the market decide it's value.  They do this because lower value to their currency gives them a great advantage in trade.  It makes their products cheaper in foreign markets.

If the market knew the composition of their foreign exchange reserves it would put more pressure on their currency to rise and it would cost China more money to keep it artificially low.